# How to make line buffering work when pipelining stderr?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, pipeline

What I want to achieve is adding timestamps before each line in a log file. The log file receives both the *stdout* and *stderr*.

```
#!/bin/sh

stdbuf -o0 -e0 continuously_running_command 2>&1 | stdbuf -o0 -e0 ts >> log_file
```

The utility *ts* adds the timestamps (I've tried to achieve this with bash code as well). *stdbuf* does not operate when using it in this pipe. When removing the pipe and redirecting only the *stderr* without adding the timestamps it works fine.

Any idea on how to fix it?

Comment: Why do you want line buffered output? I mean you are redirecting to a file.

Comment: @nick Can you elaborate a bit on what's the `continuously_running_command` you have there? If I feed this with a small endless loop printing both in _stdout_ and _stderr_ it works just fine as is.

Comment: @hek2mgl The reason I want line buffered output is because if the program terminates the last lines are not saved.

Comment: @sokin The program I'm running is rtmpdump, a video stream capturing program.

Comment: @Nick When the program terminates output buffers will get flushed. If you miss some lines, it is not a problem with buffering.

Comment: @hek2mgl how could you explain the fact that "stdbuf -o0 -e0 command 2>> log_file" runs fine but "command 2>> log_file" has the last lines missing? Also if you want to add timestamps in front of each line, wouldn't that alone be the need for line buffered pipelining?

Comment: ts will prepend *each line* with a timestamp, not each chunk of input. It's behaviour is not bound to the way how input gets buffered.

Comment: @hek2mgl I tried it and I should inform you that without stdbuf, ts is receiving a chunk of input all at once and prepends each line of it with the same time, although each line separately could have been sent for printing at different times. So what I said makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the problem is with the buffering modes used:

```
stdbuf -o0 -e0 continuously_running_command 2>&1 | stdbuf -o0 -e0 ts >> log_file
```

According to the [`stdbuf`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/stdbuf) manual page, your choice of `0` may allow the standard out and standard error to mix together in an unexpected manner:

> If *MODE* is `'L'` the corresponding stream will be line buffered. This option is invalid with standard input.
>
> If *MODE* is `'0'` the corresponding stream will be unbuffered.

When unbuffered, it means that writes from the application in anything but full lines is more likely to result in partial lines being written on either stream.  It is not uncommon for programs to write error messages in parts, e.g., a filename, then a message.  Using line-buffering reduces the likelihood of mingling incomplete lines.

Comment: I've used the L option as well.

Comment: You might try factoring the problem by redirecting standard error to `/dev/null` to see if it makes a difference.